# .net HTML.RouteLink passes parameter as key-value pair not rout

Tags: .net, razor, routelink

So in my RouteConfig I have a route that looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{GUID}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", GUID = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

And I am making a link like this:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Thing", new { controller = "Modules", action = "View", GUID = "27ACBB7C-075A-49BD-9B43-000EAE3E6B6F" })
```

I want it to create the following link:

```
<a href = ".../Modules/View/27ACBB7C-075A-49BD-9B43-000EAE3E6B6F">Thing</a>
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
<a href = ".../Modules/View?GUID=27ACBB7C-075A-49BD-9B43-000EAE3E6B6F">Thing</a>
```

How do I get RouteLink to put the parameter as a path rather than a key-value pair?

(This seems so obvious I'm sure someone's going to tell me this is a duplicate question but I've searched for the question with every keyword I know so I'll be happy to get the answer from an existing question if it already exists.)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the method inside the controller has the wrong parameter name.

inside the `Modules` controller, the `View` method should be defined as:

```
View(Guid GUID)
```